# Is there a way to prevent users from escaping the Chrome browser in kiosk mode?

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk

I have the following problem, I have a screen on which a webapp in Chrome is running in kiosk mode. I have already managed to avoid touch gestures like swiping from left to right (with a Chrome AddOn) but unfortunately you can still open the activities menu by swiping from top to bottom. You can also exit the Kiosk mode by connecting a keyboard and pressing Alt+F4 or the Windows key....

So my question is if there is a way to check if the browser is in fullscreen mode or not?

I am also open to alternative options.

Comment: What OS & release are you asking about?  (also desktop environment if not the default)

Comment: How did you implement kiosk mode? Was this done *just* in Chrome, or did you make a `.desktop` file with some additional settings to be run when a specific user account logs in?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2. I have created an script under /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart/ which starts the browser in kiosk mode.

Comment: I haven't used kiosk myself but my inclination would be to simply call chrome in a loop such that when it exits it gets run again.